# Type of UK House Construction

Tags: concrete, walls, construction, uk, old-house

not sure if this is the correct forum for this, so please let me know if it's not

Is anyone able to recognise the construction type of this house? I know it's concrete construction and likely built in the 60's. South Yorkshire area of England.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've heard types such as 'wimpey no fines' etc but I'm not 100% sure.

Attached is a picture of the attic, under the kitchen sink and a row of bricks at the base of the house.

Thank you in advance for any help.[image][image][image]

Comment: Looking up "wimpey no fines" with Google, Wikipedia describes what you have there pretty accurately.

Comment: Thank you @Jack I thought that would be the case, didn't know they used brick as a foundation though